# I am trying to connect using java to openctigraphql by the link: http://#########:8080/graphql to retrieve data

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

I am new to graphQL and opencti. I am trying to connect using java to openctigraphql by the link: http://@ip:8080/graphql to retrieve data. Is it the correct api link for opencti?

I am getting the page styling as a result, not the query data from the graphQL server.

Please can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code and how to fix it?

Thank you!

I am using the following code.

```
public class OpenCti {

    static String requestQuery = "query{stixCyberObservables{edges{node{entity_typeobservable_value}}}}";
    
    public static final String KEY = "Bearer ###############";
    public static final String URL = "http://#######:8080/graphql";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL url = new URL(URL + "?query=" + requestQuery);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", KEY);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String output;

        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((output = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(output + '\n');
        }

        in.close();
        // printing result from response
        System.out.println("Response:-" + response.toString());

    }
```